How long does it take for a Markov Chain to visit a State for the First Time?
As a learning exercise, I am trying to learn how to derive the expected time needed in a (discrete time) Markov Chain to first reach a certain state. For example, suppose we have a 5 state Markov Chain (with no absorbing states). If we start in State 1, how long will it take on average to reach State 5 for the first time? I am trying to do this without the Fundamental Theorem of Absorbing Markov Chains.
I first defined my understanding of the quantities of  interest:

Let $T_{15}$  be the random variable representing first passage time from state 1 to 5
Let $ P_{15}^{(n)} = P(\text{Chain is in state 5 at step n | Started in state 1}) $
Let $f_{15}^{(n)}$ is the probability of reaching state 5 for the FIRST time at exactly step $n$, given that we started in state 1.

As I understand, this is probability includes ALL paths that reach state 5 at step n, including those that might have visited state 5 before.
If I decompose this, logically:
$$ P_{15}^{(n)} = P(\text{First visit to 5 occurs at step n | Start at 1}) + P(\text{Visit 5 at step n but not first time | Start at 1}) $$
Using the laws of probability, I can rewrite this as:
$$ P_{15}^{(n)} = f_{15}^{(n)} + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} P(\text{First visit at k AND return at n}) $$
It took me a while to understand this**, but:
$$ P_{15}^{(n)} = f_{15}^{(n)} + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} f_{15}^{(k)} P_{55}^{(n-k)} $$
Solving for $f_{15}^{(n)}$:
$$ f_{15}^{(n)} = P_{15}^{(n)} - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} f_{15}^{(k)} P_{55}^{(n-k)} $$
$P_{ij}^{(n)}$ is typically calculated using the Chapman-Kolmogorov equation (i.e. literally identify each valid sequence and its corresponding probability):
$$ P_{ij}^{(n)} = \sum_{k=1}^{5} P_{ik}^{(n-1)} P_{kj}^{(1)} = [P^n]_{ij} $$
This is where I got stuck.
I read that Probability Generator Functions (PGFs) are often used in these types of problems. I tried to write the two PGFs for $f_{15}, P_{15}$:
$$ F_{15}(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_{15}^{(n)} s^n $$
$$ P_{15}(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P_{15}^{(n)} s^n $$
I took the above equation and multiplied both sides by $s^n$:
$$ P_{15}^{(n)} = f_{15}^{(n)} + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} f_{15}^{(k)} P_{55}^{(n-k)} $$
$$ P_{15}^{(n)}s^n = f_{15}^{(n)}s^n + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} f_{15}^{(k)} P_{55}^{(n-k)}s^n $$
I added a summation sign (over n from 1 to infinity) - the left side is just $P_{15}(s)$ by definition and the first term on the right is $F_{15}(s)$ by definition:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P_{15}^{(n)}s^n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_{15}^{(n)}s^n + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} f_{15}^{(k)} P_{55}^{(n-k)}s^n $$
Using the subtitution that $m = n-k$ and relying on the fact that $ s^n = s^k \cdot s^{n-k} $:
$$ \left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f_{15}^{(k)}s^k\right) \left(\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} P_{55}^{(m)}s^m\right) = F_{15}(s)P_{55}(s) $$
Thus:
$$ P_{15}(s) = F_{15}(s) + F_{15}(s)P_{55}(s) $$
$$ P_{15}(s) = F_{15}(s)(1 + P_{55}(s)) $$
$$ F_{15}(s) = \frac{P_{15}(s)}{1 + P_{55}(s)} $$
Finally, using the derivative-expectation properties of PGF's (evaluate at $s=1$):
$$ F'_{15}(s) = \frac{P'_{15}(s)(1 + P_{55}(s)) - P_{15}(s)P'_{55}(s)}{(1 + P_{55}(s))^2} $$
$$ E[T_{15}] = F'_{15}(1) = \frac{P'_{15}(1)(1 + P_{55}(1)) - P_{15}(1)P'_{55}(1)}{(1 + P_{55}(1))^2} $$
Thus, this would be the expected first passage time to State 5 given that we start in State 1.
Can someone please help me out here? Is my work correct?


(Note 1) Clarification on the ** note:
Starting with the total probability of being in state 5 at step $n$ (starting from state 1):
$$ P_{15}^{(n)} = P(\text{First visit at n}) + P(\text{Not first visit at n}) $$

The first term is simply $f_{15}^{(n)}$.
The second term using the law of total probability:
$$ P_{15}^{(n)} = f_{15}^{(n)} + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} P(\text{State 5 at n AND First visit to 5 was at k}) $$
If we first hit state 5 at step $k$, then getting to state 5 at step $n$ is equivalent to:

First reaching state 5 at step $k$ (probability = $f_{15}^{(k)}$)
AND THEN, starting fresh from state 5 at step $k$, reaching state 5 again after $(n-k)$ more steps (probability = $P_{55}^{(n-k)}$)

Because these events are independent once we reach state 5 for the first time. Therefore:
$$ P(\text{State 5 at n AND First visit to 5 was at k}) = f_{15}^{(k)} \cdot P_{55}^{(n-k)} $$
Substituting this back:
$$ P_{15}^{(n)} = f_{15}^{(n)} + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} f_{15}^{(k)} P_{55}^{(n-k)} $$

Note 2: If $X$ is a random variable with PGF $G_X(s)$, then:

$G'_X(1)$ gives $E[X]$
$G''_X(1)$ gives $E[X(X-1)]$
etc



Here:
$$P_{15}(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P_{15}^{(n)} s^n$$
$$P'_{15}(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nP_{15}^{(n)} s^{n-1}$$
$$P'_{55}(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nP_{55}^{(n)} s^{n-1}$$

Seems correct to me, the only technical part is this :
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f_{15}^{(k)}P_{55}^{(n-k)}s^n=
    \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty}f_{15}^{(k)}P_{55}^{(n-k)}s^{n-k}s^k =\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_{15}^{(k)}s^k\sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty}P_{55}^{(n-k)}s^{n-k}
=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_{15}^{(k)}s^k\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}P_{55}^{(m)}s^{m}=F(s)P(s)$
But you explained it thoroughly.
